# Using ST_DWithin()

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to get every parcel within 62ft of a particular road.

I use this to get the road.

```
select road_name, geom
from road
where road_name = 'marvin';
```

Now i want to find the parcels that lay on both sides of the road, going out 65ft each side.
 I was thinking about using st_DWithin .

```
select pid, geom, name
from land
ST_DWithin (select road_name, geom from road where road_name = 'marvin'), 65);
```

Is this correct?

The SRID is 26986.

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the exact spatial reference (SRID) in use.

Comment: So your search is 65 **meters**, since that's the unit of measure for that SRID.

Comment: A sub-select is not necessary for this query, so I suggest to learn how to use a LEFT JOIN, like in the previously linked [blog](http://postgis.net/2013/08/26/tip_ST_DWithin/), which will select information from two tables.

Comment: yes the same units

Comment: UPDATE NO THE UNIT IS 65FT NEED TO BE THE DISTANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally stated, PostGIS functions that work on aspects of geometry or geography require or yield values that are in the same units as those specified or implied by the CRS.

If your CRS works in meters, you'll need to convert feet measures to meters.
Multiply feet by exactly 0.3048 to get meters.

Also, you don't need to `select road_name, geom ...`, just `select geom ...`.

Comment: I am sorry for the ST_DWithin () , I need to remove the road_name , and just leave geom.